# LINQ to Objects at Runtime from Text

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any library or custom control that allows to construct LINQ to Objects (IEnumerable collection) queries at run-time from text, it would be nice to have IntelliSense support, like it is in Visual Studio code editor. I need to code CustomControl  similar to http://xte.codeplex.com/ with IntelliSense and some other features that will generate LINQ query from text.

Added: Actually i need to construct Expression not a run-time lambda code code.

Comment: the one who can create code from queries is C# compiler. you can call it in runtime.

Comment: If i will have to code this stuff by myself I wouldn't mess with C# compiler, i would rather go "text parse, lots of if/else stuff to construct expression", I'm looking for some ready solution, don't have time to code this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) does what you want, but you will have to implement Intellisense yourself...

Comment: No, it doesn't it only provide option to write expression in text. What I want is text parser that will generate expression tree.

Comment: Dynamic Linq does that: use the DynamicExpression.ParseLambda method, it returns an expression tree

Comment: Hmm I couldn't find a way to do what i want with DynamicExpression.ParseLambda you can write only expression body there. I want to be able to create expression from string like (MyObject obj)=>obj.Foo.StartsWith("sometext") && obj.Foo.Length<10